# Can I mark a controller method as POST in Play using annotations?

Tags: java, playframework, http-post

I didn't find this anywhere - can i tell Play! that a specific controller method should (only) be accessed via HTTP POST?

Something like the [HttpPost attribute](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_12) in C#'s Asp.Net MVC?

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

  @Post
  public void addPerson(String name, String address) {
  }
}
```

**Update** - I don't understand what adding a POST route do:

1. A POST request will work without adding such a route.
2. Because the method is still catched by the "Catch all" GET rule, even adding the POST route won't prevent GET requests to this method.

Comment: You need to remove the * catch all if you want your method to be accessed only via POST. That catch all should only be used for development anyway. 

It also help you see exactly what u are exposing!

Comment: @mericano1 - the catch all is great for following the Convention over Configuration idiom, I don't think it's bad for production (otherwise I'll just duplicate the lists of controllers/actions there ... more maintainence). I guess I'll submit a feature request.

Comment: Posted a ticket: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1260-ability-to-mark-controller-methods-as-post-by-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
public static void onlyPost() {
  if (request.method.equals("POST")) {
     // ... Do stuff
     render(); 
  }
  else
    forbidden();
}
```

But keep in mind that your code and your routes file might be out of sync.

Also, you can use Groovy code inside the routes file, so no need for duplication.

```
# Catch all
#{if play.mode.isDev()}
*   /{controller}/{action}       {controller}.{action}
#{/if}
```

Comment: Cool about groovy in routes - but that's besides the point - I need the code to work in Prod, not just Dev.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because that's the next best thing to what I wanted - but please see the issue I opened about marking this with an annotation - https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1260-ability-to-mark-controller-methods-as-post-by-annotation

Comment: The Groovy code above disables the catch all in Prod, it implements what @mericano1 suggested. But let's see if they accept your ticket. What HTTP response do you expect when someone accesses your action with the wrong method?

Comment: I guess 404 would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

You do this in the routes file:

```
POST /person/add   MyController.addPerson
```

There is more documentation on this [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/routes).

Comment: I saw this option, but it feels a bit awkward. Also, even if I add this route, this method will also respond to GET requests, because it will match the default "Catch all" route. 

Are there plans to allow setting this via an annotation? Should I submit a feature request?

Answer (score 2):

i'm a little late to the party. 
afaik there's no built in annotation, 
but you can quite easily write one yourself:

annotations/HttpMethod.java

```
/**
 * Add this annotation to your controller actions to force a get/post request. 
 * This is checked in globals.java, so ensure you also have @With(Global.class) 
 * in your controller
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface HttpMethod{
    String method() default "POST";
}
```

controllers/Global.java

```
/**
 * All the funky global stuff ... 
 */
public class Global extends Controller{

    @Before
    public static void before(){
        if( getActionAnnotation( HttpMethod.class ) != null ){
            HttpMethod method = getActionAnnotation( HttpMethod.class ); 
            if( !method.method().equals( request.method ) ){
                error( "Don't be evil! " ); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

usage: 
controllers/Admin.java

```
@With({Global.class, Secure.class})
public class Admin extends Controller {
    @HttpMethod(method="POST")
    public static void save( MyModel model ){
        // yey...
    }
}
```